# open set $O$ such that $\partial(\overline{O})$ has positive measure

Tags: measure-theory

Find an open set $O$ such that $\partial(\overline{O})$ has positive measure. The hint is to consider a Cantor set, with positive measure.

But that does not work, because all the Cantors are closed and nowhere dense, thus I don't know how to generate the open with this sets.

Please help me

Comment: The hint means $O$ is the complement of a cantor type set and the Cantor set will be the boundary.

Comment: But the complement of a Cantor set it's dense over an interval, thus the boundary of the closure has zero measure

Comment: Oh, then you can just chose some of the intervals to the complement to get the right boundary of the closure.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
Consider a "[fat cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set)" and use Rene's comment.

Comment: In that example I don't know what is the boundary of the Volterra Cantor Set. How can I found it?

Comment: The fat cantor set has no interior points, so it is itself. Check it!

Comment: The Fat Cantor Set, does not work because it's $\overline{O}=[0,1]$ thus $\partial(\overline{O})=[0,1]$.

Comment: You have to use Rene's second comment.